# How to create a global bidimensional array whose size is only defined at runtime in c (or how to pass arguments to drawing functions in opengl)?

Tags: c, arrays, opengl

I want to create a bidimensional array that represents the positions of a board game. I've defined that each position is of type 'struct position' which is a enum that can be 'empty', 'piece1' or 'piece2'. The problem is that the user decides which size the table is, that is, how many positions the bidimensional array will have. Since I'm calling graphic functions of opengl which can't take arguments (or is there a way for them to do that?), is it possible to define the size of the bidimensional array at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't define the size of an array at run-time in C. But one-dimensional arrays have the same semantics as pointers, so you can "emulate" a multi-dimensional by using pointers instead. Something like this should do the trick:

```
int w = 16, h = 16;
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * w * h);

int x = 4, y = 2;
array[y * w + x] = 1;
```

Comment: You might find it useful to have not just width and height but also "stride" - the offset between a cell and the corresponding cell in the next row. This makes it easy to treat one grid as a sub-grid of another (by keeping stride the same but changing width/height and the base pointer) and likewise allows you to flip the grid upside down or skip every other row just by changing the stride. This technique is especially useful in video-processing applications but could be nice in games too.

Comment: And if it wasn't clear: using `stride` just means computing the array index as `y*stride+x` instead of `y*h+x`, but still using `w` and `h` as the bounds for `x` and `y`.

Comment: By the way, if you're iterating over rows, don't keep multiplying `y*stride` or `y*w` over and over. Instead, keep a pointer to the current row, and increment it by `stride` or `w` at each iteration.